# Re-entering Bulgaria

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules, bulgaria

I have an Australian passport and have stayed 90 days in Bulgaria but have now left. I first entered the country on September 16th 2018.

My question is am I able to re-enter the country 180 days after my initial entry date (which would  mean I can go back in March) for another 90 days without needing to apply for a visa? Or now that the 90 days have been used to re-enter will I need a visa?

Comment: I believe you want to enter 181 days after your first arrival, not 180. Also, remember your partial days of arrival and departure both count as full days. From the 90/180 rule, you are OK. Nevertheless, you may find the border guard curious how you are able to support yourself for such extended stays. They can always refuse you.

Answer (score 3):

Bulgaria follows the same 90/180 days entry rules the Schengen area follows, but separate from it.

That means that if you have been in the country for 90 days in one block you need to be out of the country for 90 more days before you can come back in.
If your stay was less than 90 days or if your visits have been split in several shorter visits, the rule is that you can enter if you have been in the country for less than 90 days in the last 180 days.

It is a rolling period, so any day you have to be out of the country for at least 90 days in the last 180.

And that is not just whole days, it is any part of a day. If you leave a few minutes after midnight, those few minutes count as a whole day and if you enter a few minutes before midnight those also count as a whole day. And if you have to enter the country to change flights, so get a stamp in your passport, that also count as a visit.

On the other hand, there is not something like 'have used your days' and need a visa now. Either you are allowed in, with a visa replacing stamp or with a visa, or you are not allowed in. The only exception is if you need a stay longer than 90 days like for studies or work, for that you need a visa, but that is separate from the visitor stamp in your passport as Australian short term visitor.

I answered this question based on my knowledge of the rules, could not find a link for you right now.
I double checked on [an IATA site.](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/BG-Bulgaria-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm)

[According to this site](https://www.etiaseurope.eu/etias-requirements/australian/bulgaria/) from the start of 2021* an ETIAS authorisation will be required and Bulgaria will be part of [the Schengen zone](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-countries-list/) some time in the future but it is not yet now.
When Bulgaria enters the Schengen zone your stays there will be added to the stays in the rest of the Schengen zone and the total stay restricted to 90 days out of 180 days.
*According to [the official site for ETIAS](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/smart-borders/etias_en) the system is not running yet and it might be not before well into 2022.

Comment: The site you've linked to is a third-party site.  The official EU site (https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/smart-borders/etias_en) says that ETIAS is currently expected to be operational in late 2022.  That page also links to a document that notes that ETIAS will be required to visit the countries that are in the process of joining the Schengen area, including Bulgaria, even before they have been completely integrated into it.